# Bind docker container to IP on OSX

Tags: ip, docker, containers

On Ubuntu I do something like this

```
sudo ip addr add 192.168.33.30/21 dev eth0
docker run -p 192.168.33.30:80:80 -d foo/bar /sbin/my_init
```

Then I can open up a browser at http://192.168.33.30.

How would I accomplish the same thing on OSX?

(OSX has no 'ip addr' and this boot2docker-vm thing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution working for me:

```
# Register IP address
sudo ifconfig lo0 add 192.168.33.30

# Run docker container with port 80 assigned to random free port
docker run -p 80 --name boing -d foo/bar /sbin/my_init

# Start SSH tunnel for port 80 (http)
TUNNEL_ADDR_PORT_80=$(docker port boing | grep 80 | awk '{print $3}')
sudo ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
        -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -i $HOME/.ssh/id_boot2docker \
        -nNT -f -L 192.168.33.30:80:$TUNNEL_ADDR_PORT_80 \
        docker@$(boot2docker ip 2>/dev/null) &
```